# How do I force simple_form to set the fields of an existing resource to be blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

This is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => invitation_path(resource_name), :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
   <%= devise_error_messages2! %>
      <% resource.class.invite_key_fields.each do |field| -%>
        <%= f.input :first_name, label: "Family Member's First Name:", input_html: { maxlength: 15, size: 40 } %>
        <%= f.input :last_name, label: "Family Member's Last Name:", input_html: { maxlength: 15, size: 40 } %>                                         
        <%= f.input :gender, label: "Gender", collection: User.genders.keys %>
        <%= f.input :email, label: "Email:" %>
        <%= f.input :invitation_relation, label: "I am his/her (relation):", collection: relation_types, label_method: :humanize, include_blank: false %>
                    <% end -%>

                    <%= f.submit t("devise.invitations.new.submit_button") %>
                    <% end %>
```

When the user goes to this form, they see pre-filled fields (which is cool in most circumstances). But I want to set the fields to be blank in this case.

How do I do that?

I tried adding `placeholder: ''` but that didn't work. In fact, if I tried to override the placeholder by doing something like `placeholder: "John Brown"` that didn't show up either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit the HTML value of the field by default to nothing.

`input_html: { value: nil }`